# Stop script inside an other script - Adobe Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe

Good Day everyone,

In an adobe form I'm trying to use the differences between 2 dates to stop a script... But the only thing I can do is to stop the function making the calculation and not the full script...

So I have a full "Submit" script inside that script I have the following to calculate between the 2 dates.:

```
function ValidateCleanAndSubmit(){

  var OffEndDate = GetFieldValue("official_endate");
  var datearray = OffEndDate.split("-");
  var EndDate = new Date(datearray[0],datearray[1] - 1,datearray[2]);

  var DateDiff =
  {
    inDays: function(d1, d2)
    {
      var t2 = d2.getTime();
      var t1 = d1.getTime();
      if((parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000))) > 7)
      {
        app.alert("The Official End Date is in more than 7 days therefore you cannot submit the form.\rPlease save the form and do it later (section 10).");
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  var d1 = new Date(EndDate);
  var d2 = new Date();

  DateDiff.inDays(d2, d1);

  eformpdfSubmit();

}
```

It does what it's supposed to display the error message BUT it keep running the full Submit script... How can I completely stop the script to run... Cause it basically stop the "Function" in the not the full submit script.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return `false` from the submit handler it will cancel the submit event.

You can change your `DateDiff.inDays` call to into:

```
if (!DateDiff.inDays(d2, d1)) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Added full "Submit" function